# Как получить записи, где нет заданного типа после group by

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы. Клиентов и их действий.
Надо получить тех клиентов, у которых нет конкретного действия. Таблицы выглядят вот так, исходные данные:

clients:

```
empId   name
1       Clark
2       Dave
3       Ava
4       Avaaad
```

actions:

```
empId   cliId   typeAct
1       1       1
2       1       2
3       2       2
4       3       3
5       1       3
```

Можете посмотреть в [онлайн mysql](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yv842whr)

Сделал следующий запрос. Он выбирает клиентов и их действия. Выбор клиента без действий не составляет труда. Можно просто дописать `WHERE actions.typeAct IS NULL`, а вот как выбрать клиентов, у которых нет конкретного действия? Каким-то подзапросом или это уже через PHP делать?

```
SELECT name, typeAct FROM clients
left join actions on actions.cliId=clients.empId
group by clients.name, actions.typeAct;
```

Вывод:

```
name    typeAct
Clark   3
Clark   2
Clark   1
Dave    2
Ava     3
Avaaad  NULL
```

Ожидания, например для тех, у кого нет действия 2:

```
name    typeAct
Ava     3
Avaaad  NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT c.name, a.typeAct 
    FROM clients c
    LEFT JOIN actions a on a.cliId=c.empId AND a.typeAct != 2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM actions ac WHERE ac.cliId = c.empId AND ac.typeAct = 2)
    GROUP BY c.name, a.typeAct;
```

Объяснение:

Грубо говоря, проверяем все `actions` с `typeAct = 2` на существование с конкретным `empId`. Если находим хотя бы одно, то не учитываем в выборке